# OpenCL (aparapi) simple reduction slow on Radeon

Tags: opencl, aparapi

I am trying to code a simple reduction (in this case a sum) over a large double array in OpenCL. I have looked at online tutorials and found that this is essentially the way to solve my problem:

```
#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_fp64 : enable

typedef struct This_s{
   __global double *nums;
   int nums__javaArrayLength;
   __local double *buffer;
   __global double *res;
   int passid;
}This;
int get_pass_id(This *this){
   return this->passid;
}
__kernel void run(
   __global double *nums, 
   int nums__javaArrayLength, 
   __local double *buffer, 
   __global double *res, 
   int passid
){
   This thisStruct;
   This* this=&thisStruct;
   this->nums = nums;
   this->nums__javaArrayLength = nums__javaArrayLength;
   this->buffer = buffer;
   this->res = res;
   this->passid = passid;
   {
      int tid = get_local_id(0);
      int i = (get_group_id(0) * get_local_size(0)) + get_local_id(0);
      int gridSize = get_local_size(0) * get_num_groups(0);
      int n = this->nums__javaArrayLength;
      double cur = 0.0;
      for (; i<n; i = i + gridSize){
         cur = cur + this->nums[i];
      }
      this->buffer[tid]  = cur;
      barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
      barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
      if (tid<32){
         this->buffer[tid]  = this->buffer[tid] + this->buffer[(tid + 32)];
      }
      barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
      if (tid<16){
         this->buffer[tid]  = this->buffer[tid] + this->buffer[(tid + 16)];
      }
      barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
      if (tid<8){
         this->buffer[tid]  = this->buffer[tid] + this->buffer[(tid + 8)];
      }
      barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
      if (tid<4){
         this->buffer[tid]  = this->buffer[tid] + this->buffer[(tid + 4)];
      }
      barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
      if (tid<2){
         this->buffer[tid]  = this->buffer[tid] + this->buffer[(tid + 2)];
      }
      barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
      if (tid<1){
         this->buffer[tid]  = this->buffer[tid] + this->buffer[(tid + 1)];
      }
      barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
      if (tid==0){
         this->res[get_group_id(0)]  = this->buffer[0];
      }
      return;
   }
}
```

If you are wondering about the strange `this`, that is an (unfortunately necessary) artifact of aparapi, which I use to translate Java to OpenCL.

My kernel produces the correct results and, on reasonably beefy Nvidia Hardware, it is about 10x faster than a sequential sum in Java. On a Radeon R9 280 however it is comparable in performance to the simple Java code.

I have profiled the kernel with CodeXL. It tells me that MemUnitBusy is at just 6%. Why is it so low?

Comment: I opened a ticket for this and added a bounty here: https://github.com/Syncleus/aparapi/issues/107

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out OpenCL is not (directly) at fault, but aparapis buffer management is.

I tried out the exact same kernel without aparapi, and the performance is good. It turns bad as soon as I use `CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR`, which is sadly the only option when using aparapi. It seems AMD is not copying host memory to the device with that option, even after several "warmup" runs.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider moving to the more active project at [aparapi.com](http://aparapi.com). It includes several fixes to bugs and a lot of extra features and performance enhancements over the older library you linked above. It is also in maven central with about a dozen releases. so it is easier to use. The new [Github repository is here](https://github.com/Syncleus/aparapi).